# Как очистить корневую папку? Если она заполнена

Tags: ubuntu

Всем привет. Ребят никто незнает как очистить корневую папку? Она заполнена на 94% и я незнаю как удалить ненужные файлы которые там есть? Удалял с помощью команд autoclean,autoremove, clean ничего из этого не помогает.Может она просто переполнена нужными файлами и я слишком мало ей разметил место?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пройлись прогой `ncdu`.

Answer (score 1):

Почитайте, ну хотя бы вот это:

http://www.codernotes.ru/articles/administrirovanie-linux/chem-zanyato-mesto-na-diske-linux.html

никто кроме Вас не может Вам сказать, каким хламом забит корень... Но одну могу сказать точно: выделять под корень 7.4 ГБ - неверное решение абсолютно. Ну хотя бы 50 ГБ нужно. Если у вас совсем крошечный диск. А лучше > 100 ГБ.

Comment: Зависит. У меня / 770 мегабайт, занято 400. Естественно, всё, что можно — не на корне, потому что большой корень больнее и статистически вероятнее падает.

Answer (score 1):

Согласен с предыдущим комментатором в части того, что места выделено мало. Так как вижу что тот же /usr и /var  у вас не отдельные диски.
Ну и посмотрите чем занято место:

```
du -h -d 1 - выполните в корне ("/")
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы считаете каждый мегабайт, то можно удалить snap и устанавливать программы только из обычных репозиториев. Snap-пакеты устроены так, что они тянут вместе с собой все зависимости вместо использования уже имеющихся в системе. Кроме того это куча мусорных демонов и виртуальных девайсов, которые вряд ли хорошо отражаются на общей производительности.

```
sudo apt purge snap*
sudo rm -r /var/cache/snapd
```